# Pass quoted variable to function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to pass a quoted variable to a react function. So in the example I would like to have "mq" replaced with a $name variable including double quotes. Instead of this:

```js
if (test === "PER") {
    var aggs = () => ({
        aggs: {
            "mq": {
                significant_terms: {
                    field: feld,
                    percentage: {},
                    size: 10
                }
            },
        },
    });
}
```

I would like to have the following:

```js
if (test === "PER") {
    var aggs = () => ({
        aggs: {
            "MQTT": {
                significant_terms: {
                    field: feld,
                    percentage: {},
                    size: 10
                }
            },
        },
    });
}
```

Where "MQTT" comes from a variable, e.g. `let name="MQTT";` because this part is variable in my Application... But i have no clue on how to pass that name variable to the `var aggs=() =>`correctly. Hope somebody can help me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let name = 'MQTT'
if (test === 'PER') {
    var aggs = () => ({
        aggs: {
            [name]: {
                significant_terms: {
                    field: feld,
                    percentage: {},
                    size: 10
                },
            },
        },
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is answered already. However, as a suggestion you can follow this answer.

For any `dynamic key` in the object you can use `[key]`. Below are a few examples.

```js
let obj = {
  ["test"]: "test",
};
console.log(obj); // { test: 'test' }

const key = "test2";
obj = {
  [key]: key,
};
console.log(obj); // { test2: 'test2' }

const key3 = "test3";
obj = {};
obj[key3] = key3;
console.log(obj); // { test3: 'test3' }
```

**For your question:**

```
function aggregatorBuilder(test) {
  var aggs = null;
  if (test === "PER") {
    aggs = (key) => ({
      aggs: {
        [key]: { // dymanic key
          significant_terms: {
            field: feld,
            percentage: {},
            size: 10,
          },
        },
      },
    });
  }
  return aggs;
}
```